# Trying to identify more info about PDF Producer "3.0.0.M8 (5.0.0.M4)"

Tags: pdf, producer

I'm checking the metadata of a PDF file which has been altered.  I'm trying to identify the software used to make the change.  Anyone help?  Thanks.

Metadata identified in Adobe Reader